# Python code for D-Wave Annealer

Tags: optimization, d-wave, annealing, adiabatic-model, programming

In the below screenshot, I am aware of resolving the issue by reducing `num_reads` as the annealing time is exceeding my allowance. Although it works, my question with this error is different.

[image]
[image]

The error says that the problem cannot be submitted while I am trying to access the value of the variable `sample_set`.
I expected the error to have occurred while executing:

```
sample_set = sampler.sample(bqm, num_reads=10000)
```

It seems like the problem is being submitted while I access the variable `sample_set`.

So, my question is, when do the following things happen in the code?

- problem submission
- mapping of logical to physical qubits
- annealer solving the problem

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I received an answer in the D-Wave community.

https://support.dwavesys.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/17281010426519-When-is-the-problem-submitted-w-r-t-the-code-